# how to "bounce" social nav icons on hover/focus?

Tags: css

Hi friendly peeps at stack,

Anyone know how the following CSS hover effect is produced at:

http://seanwes.com/

There are a few other tutorials on stack overflow for replacing the social nav icon with an replacement image (general colored) flip-style - i just want it to bounce up and keep the image the same. thinking it may have something to do with:

```
-webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
-o-transition: all .2s linear;
-moz-transition: all .2s linear;
transition: all .2s linear;
```

thoughts? thanks!

Comment: If you _think_ it may have to do with $something – then why don’t you _research_ $something before you ask?

Comment: CBroe - i did, and couldn't find the answer. so i posted a question here. if you don't like this then please keep your assumptions to yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is very simple

When you hover the `<li>` they apply a negative margin.This is the html code of the bar

```
<ul id="social" class="msixcol mlast mright">
    <li id="twitter" class="fade"><a href="http://twitter.com/seanwes/" class="r">twitter</a></li>
    <li id="facebook" class="fade"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/seanwes" class="r">facebook</a></li>
    <li id="dribbble" class="fade"><a href="http://dribbble.com/seanwes" class="r">dribbble</a></li>
    <li id="instagram" class="fade"><a href="http://instagram.com/seanwes" class="r">instagram</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is the css line that does the magic trick:

```
#social li:hover { margin-top: -3px; }
```

And the transition just gives the smooth effect:

```
a,.fade,input,textarea { -webkit-transition: all .2s linear; -o-transition: all .2s linear; -moz-transition: all .2s linear; transition: all .2s linear; }
```

Comment: + applying the transition.

Comment: thanks christoph! can't get it to work in jsfiddle though, anyone have any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/ttoven/PyJZb/

Answer (score 1):

hi this is quite simple here some code for the basics:

CSS:

```
.image{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.transition{
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}

.image:hover{
    box-shadow:0px 0px 15px 0px black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="image transition"></div>
```

in this way you can apply transition as a class to any element you want and remember that the transition is applied on every thing you write in :hover.

[here is a working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GQVyH/)

and here is some code for applying this in a list:

CSS:

```
ul{list-style:none; float:left;}
ul li{margin:15px;}
.image{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
}

.transition{
    -webkit-transition: all .2s linear;
    -o-transition: all .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .2s linear;
    transition: all .2s linear;
}

.image:hover{
    box-shadow:0px 0px 15px 0px black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="image transition"></li>
    <li class="image transition"></li>
    <li class="image transition"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="image transition"></li>
    <li class="image transition"></li>
    <li class="image transition"></li>
</ul>
```

and the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GQVyH/1/) as always

now you just need to replace the `background:red;` property to
 `background-image:url(yourimagepath.ext);` and you should be ready to go.

Comment: i edited the answer so you can see how it should look in an unordered list, with a fiddle of course